# Struts2 Hidden field within iterator

Tags: struts2, iterator, hidden

When using a hidden field within an iterator, why does it matter if the hidden field is within a tr tag?  If it isn't it doesn't pass the value to the Action when the form is submitted.

For instance, the code below returns null to the Action for updatedData.transactionId...

```
<s:iterator value="adjustmentData" status="rowStatus">
  <s:hidden name="updatedData[%{#rowStatus.index}].transactionId" value="%{transactionId}" />
  <tr>
```

However the code below works....

```
<s:iterator value="adjustmentData" status="rowStatus">
  <tr>
    <s:hidden name="updatedData[%{#rowStatus.index}].transactionId" value="%{transactionId}" />
```

Why does it matter if the hidden tag is within the tr tag?

In each case, the field created is the same.

```
<tbody>
  <input type="hidden" name="updatedData[0].transactionId" value="199984" id="updateAdjForm_updatedData_0__transactionId"/>
  <tr>

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="updatedData[0].transactionId" value="199984" id="updateAdjForm_updatedData_0__transactionId"/>
```

Comment: Having the input outside of the tr is not valid HTML markup and will not pass html validation rules.  It will probably render fine in most browsers though.  Permitted content of the tbody is TR only.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody

Comment: How do you submit your form?